TraceId not printing in kafka-stream application
I have kafka stream application which is running in springboot-2.x, kafka-streams-2.5.1 and spring-cloud-sleuth (log tracing) and I’m using KafkaStreamsTracing for print traceId and spanId. Which is working fine without issue.
Now we are upgrading our application into springboot-3.3.4, kafka-stream-3.7.1 and io.metrix (log tracing) after upgrade traceId and spanId is not printing in kafka-stream.
Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId> <!-- version 3.2.4 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId> <!-- version 3.7.1 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId> <!-- version 1.3.4 -->
    </dependency>


Make sure you've set spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.enableObservation to true. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html for details
